# How do I copy the name of the song currently playing on an internet radio station in iTunes?

Tags: itunes, streaming

I frequently feel like Googling, YouTubing, or downloading some song playing on an internet radio station.  Mac OS X's iTunes displays the song information, but doesn't provide any obvious route to copying the song's author, name, etc.

I'm not interested if the iTunes Store offers relevant features because I always keep the iTunes Store disabled in parental controls.

Comment: Have you tried Last FM and Scrobbling? (worth googleing it)

Comment: Can you please clarify if you are using OS X, iOS, or both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this AppleScript to copy the current stream title to the clipboard:

```
tell application "iTunes"
    set stream_title to (get current stream title)
end tell

set the clipboard to stream_title
display dialog stream_title & " copied to clipboard." -- delete line to omit dialog
```

To install it as iTunes script, copy & paste the above into the **AppleScript Editor** and save it under `Library/iTunes/Scripts` in your home folder, giving it a sensible name, such as `Copy Stream Title to Clipboard`. Create the `Scripts` folder if it doesn't exist. This will make iTunes grow a little script icon in it's menu bar where you can select the script.

[image]

Comment: Very elegant, thanks!  I could even simply log all the song names played for perusing after the fact.

Answer (score 0):

I often take a screenshot of iTunes when it is displaying the relevant information. It's not the direct workflow you're asking for, but it's simple to do (Cmd-Shift-4, then press space, to take a screenshot of a specific window, if you're talking about OS X here) and the info becomes hard to lose.